# Is there a function $h_2$ such that $h_2^{(k)}(0)\neq 0$ and $h_2\sim f$, which satisfies $f^{(n)}(0)=0$ for all $n$?

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be $e^{1/x}$ for $x<0$ and $0$ otherwise. I look for functions $h_1,h_2$ such that
$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f(x)}{h_1(x)}=1$$
and
$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\varphi(x)-\varphi(0)h_2(x)}{h_1(x)}$$
converges for every $\varphi\in C^\infty$.

My intuition says that I should seek a function $h_1$ such that $h_1^{(k)}(0)\neq 0$ for some $k$. However, I don't know if this is possible by the first restriction.